# Ruby undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) before method call

Tags: ruby, openshift

New to ruby and openshift so not sure what I'm doing.

When I push my ruby code to git and the build is kicked off I get this error.

```
remote: Building Ruby cartridge
remote: /var/lib/openshift/234325h2345234523452/app-root/runtime/repo/GetMovieRTRating.rb:23:in `Rating': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
remote:         from /var/lib/openshift/234325h2345234523452/app-root/runtime/repo/createCinemaTweets.rb:74:in `Run'
remote:         from /var/lib/openshift/234325h2345234523452/app-root/runtime/repo/Driver.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:         from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
remote:         from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
remote: going to call rating 0 "Teenage%20Mutant%20Ninja%20Turtles", 2014
remote: Got the rating from the script: 22%
remote: going to call rating 1 "Teenage%20Mutant%20Ninja%20Turtles", 2014
remote: Got the rating from the script: 22%
remote: going to call rating 2 "The%20Maze%20Runner", 2014
remote: Got the rating from the script: 63%
remote: going to call rating 3 "The%20Maze%20Runner", 2014
remote: Got the rating from the script: 63%
remote: going to call rating 4 "The%20Maze%20Runner", 2014
remote: Got the rating from the script: 63%
remote: going to call rating 5 "Gone%20Girl", 2014
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute action hook 'build' for application 
remote:
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
```

the Rating method does work cause I'm getting the correct ratings back after this error is thrown but the interpreter is throwing the undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError). I presume this is causing the failed action hook build unless its the other way round?
This is the class

```
class Rotten  

def Rating(movie="terminator", year=1984)    
    @rottenKey="<key>"
    @movie = movie.gsub(/\"/i, '')
    @requiredYear = year.to_i

    @url = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=#{@movie}&page_limit=50&apikey=#{@rottenKey}"

    resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(@url))
    data = resp.body

    @i=0
    @parsedData = JSON.parse(data)['movies']

    while @i < 50 do
      @foundYear = @parsedData[@i]['year'].to_i
      @rating = @parsedData[@i]['ratings']['critics_score']

      @i +=1
      if @foundYear - @requiredYear == 0 then
        return "#{@rating}%"
      end
    end
 end  
end
```

And I call it from the other class with

`@rating = Rotten.new.Rating("#{@movieTitleURL}",@ratingYear)`

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason that you use @ for most of the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with your attempt for `@rating` chances are that

```
@parsedData[@i]['ratings']
#=> nil
```

Since you are then calling `[]` on `nil` this will fail. you could try something like the following (although I cannot test because I do not have an API Key)

```
class Rotten  
  @@rotten_key = "<key>"
  def self.rating(movie="terminator", required_year=1984)    
    @movie = movie.gsub(/\"/i, '')

    @url = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=#{@movie}&page_limit=50&apikey=#{@@rotten_key}"

    resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(@url))

    JSON.parse(resp.body)['movies'].take(50).find({ratings:{}})do |obj| 
       obj['year'].to_i == required_year.to_i
    end['ratings']['critics_score']
  end  
end
```

Notice cleaned some things up like unimportant instance variables and naming conventions (ruby syntax is written in snake_case not camelCase). You can call this with `Rotten.rating("movie name", year)`

If I were you I would build this out a bit further though to something more like

```
class Rotten
  attr_accessor :movie, :requested_year
  @@rotten_key = "<key>"
  @@rotten_url = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?page_limit=50&apikey=#{@@rotten_key}"

  def initialize(movie, requested_year)
    @movie = movie.gsub(/\"/i, '')
    @requested_year = requested_year
  end
  def ratings
    movie_data['ratings'] || {}
  end
  def critics_score
    ratings['critics_score'].to_i
  end
  def movie_data
    @movie_data ||= get_movie_data
  end

  private
    def get_movie_data
      resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(@@rotten_url + "&movie=#{@movie}"))
      JSON.parse(resp.body)['movies'].find({}){|movie| movie['year'].to_i == @year}
    end
end
```

This will give you more access inside the instance variable e.g.

```
movie = Rotten.new('terminator',1984)
movie.movie
#=>'terminator'
movie.requested_year
#=> 1984
movie.ratings
#=>{'critics_score' => 89, 'some_other_score'=>67}
movie.critics_score
#=> 89
movie.movie_data
#=>{'ratings' => {'critics_score' => 89, 'some_other_score'=>67}, 'year' => 1984}
```

**I might have gotten a bit carried away with this answer as it seemed like a fun problem but I will be happy to explain everything that is happening here if you would like.**

Comment: Thanks for fleshing this out in proper Ruby. I'll implement your changes and report back. Can you comment on the error I'm getting before I even call the Rating method?

Comment: @JimmyCasey it says the error is at line 23 in `GetMovieRTRating.rb` I do not know if that is the file we are looking at or not so it is hard to say but if you look at that line it should give you some indication of what is returning `nil`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your class structure removed the error.

Comment: @JimmyCasey I am glad it worked for you. When I started in ruby I did many things the way you did with complex methods that I was used to in other languages. You will find with Ruby the more you can partition the methods into smaller more concise ones the easier it will be to manage you code and add features quickly.